Snaps won't open
After a power outage yesterday, my Ubuntu system is unable to open any snaps, not even the snap store.
If I run snap version I get:
snap    2.65.3

snapd   2.65.3

series  16

ubuntu  24.04

kernel  6.8.0-45-generic

If I try to open a snap using the CLI, say, Firefox, I get this message:
snap-confine has elevated permissions and is not confined but should be. Refusing to continue to avoid permission escalation attacks
Please make sure that the snapd.apparmor service is enabled and started.

I have tried following everything on this thread to no use.
The output of sudo aa-status is:
apparmor module is loaded.
234 profiles are loaded.
135 profiles are in enforce mode.
   /snap/core/17200/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine
   /snap/core/17200/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine//mount-namespace-capture-helper
   /snap/snapd/21759/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine
   /snap/snapd/21759/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine//mount-namespace-capture-helper
   /usr/bin/evince
   /usr/bin/evince-previewer
   /usr/bin/evince-previewer//sanitized_helper
   /usr/bin/evince-thumbnailer
   /usr/bin/evince//sanitized_helper
   /usr/bin/evince//snap_browsers
   /usr/bin/man
   /usr/lib/cups/backend/cups-pdf
   /usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine
   /usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine//mount-namespace-capture-helper
   /usr/sbin/cups-browsed
   /usr/sbin/cupsd
   /usr/sbin/cupsd//third_party
   avahi-daemon
   dnsmasq
   dnsmasq//libvirt_leaseshelper
   identd
   klogd
   libreoffice-senddoc
   libreoffice-soffice//gpg
   libreoffice-xpdfimport
   lsb_release
   man_filter
   man_groff
   mdnsd
   nmbd
   nscd
   nvidia_modprobe
   nvidia_modprobe//kmod
   php-fpm
   ping
   plasmashell
   plasmashell//QtWebEngineProcess
   rsyslogd
   samba-bgqd
   samba-dcerpcd
   samba-rpcd
   samba-rpcd-classic
   samba-rpcd-spoolss
   smbd
   smbldap-useradd
   smbldap-useradd///etc/init.d/nscd
   snap-update-ns.audacity
   snap-update-ns.canonical-livepatch
   snap-update-ns.core
   snap-update-ns.discord
   snap-update-ns.firefox
   snap-update-ns.firmware-updater
   snap-update-ns.flasharch
   snap-update-ns.gnome-mines
   snap-update-ns.gs
   snap-update-ns.melonds
   snap-update-ns.notepad-plus-plus
   snap-update-ns.opera
   snap-update-ns.slack
   snap-update-ns.snap-store
   snap-update-ns.snapd-desktop-integration
   snap-update-ns.spotify
   snap-update-ns.steam
   snap-update-ns.telegram-desktop
   snap-update-ns.thunderbird
   snap-update-ns.whatsie
   snap.audacity.audacity
   snap.canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatch
   snap.canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd
   snap.canonical-livepatch.hook.configure
   snap.canonical-livepatch.hook.connect-plug-etc-update-motd-d
   snap.canonical-livepatch.hook.disconnect-plug-etc-update-motd-d
   snap.canonical-livepatch.hook.post-refresh
   snap.canonical-livepatch.hook.remove
   snap.core.hook.configure
   snap.discord.discord
   snap.discord.hook.configure
   snap.firefox.firefox
   snap.firefox.geckodriver
   snap.firefox.hook.configure
   snap.firefox.hook.disconnect-plug-host-hunspell
   snap.firefox.hook.post-refresh
   snap.firmware-updater.firmware-notifier
   snap.firmware-updater.firmware-updater
   snap.firmware-updater.firmware-updater-app
   snap.firmware-updater.hook.configure
   snap.flasharch.flasharch
   snap.gnome-mines.gnome-mines
   snap.gnome-mines.hook.configure
   snap.melonds.hook.configure
   snap.melonds.melonds
   snap.notepad-plus-plus.hook.configure
   snap.notepad-plus-plus.notepad-plus-plus
   snap.notepad-plus-plus.wine
   snap.notepad-plus-plus.winetricks
   snap.opera.hook.configure
   snap.opera.opera
   snap.slack.hook.configure
   snap.slack.slack
   snap.snap-store.hook.configure
   snap.snap-store.show-updates
   snap.snap-store.snap-store
   snap.snapd-desktop-integration.hook.configure
   snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration
   snap.spotify.hook.configure
   snap.spotify.spotify
   snap.steam.glxgears
   snap.steam.glxinfo
   snap.steam.hook.configure
   snap.steam.report
   snap.steam.steam
   snap.steam.test
   snap.steam.vkcube
   snap.steam.vulkaninfo
   snap.telegram-desktop.hook.configure
   snap.telegram-desktop.telegram-desktop
   snap.thunderbird.hook.configure
   snap.thunderbird.thunderbird
   snap.whatsie.whatsie
   syslog-ng
   syslogd
   tcpdump
   traceroute
   ubuntu_pro_apt_news
   ubuntu_pro_esm_cache
   ubuntu_pro_esm_cache//apt_methods
   ubuntu_pro_esm_cache//apt_methods_gpgv
   ubuntu_pro_esm_cache//cloud_id
   ubuntu_pro_esm_cache//dpkg
   ubuntu_pro_esm_cache//ps
   ubuntu_pro_esm_cache//ubuntu_distro_info
   ubuntu_pro_esm_cache_systemctl
   ubuntu_pro_esm_cache_systemd_detect_virt
   unix-chkpwd
   unprivileged_userns
8 profiles are in complain mode.
   /usr/sbin/sssd
   libreoffice-oosplash
   libreoffice-soffice
   snap.gs.gs
   transmission-cli
   transmission-daemon
   transmission-gtk
   transmission-qt
0 profiles are in prompt mode.
0 profiles are in kill mode.
91 profiles are in unconfined mode.
   1password
   Discord
   MongoDB Compass
   QtWebEngineProcess
   balena-etcher
   brave
   buildah
   busybox
   cam
   ch-checkns
   ch-run
   chrome
   crun
   devhelp
   element-desktop
   epiphany
   evolution
   firefox
   flatpak
   foliate
   geary
   github-desktop
   goldendict
   ipa_verify
   kchmviewer
   keybase
   lc-compliance
   libcamerify
   linux-sandbox
   loupe
   lxc-attach
   lxc-create
   lxc-destroy
   lxc-execute
   lxc-stop
   lxc-unshare
   lxc-usernsexec
   mmdebstrap
   msedge
   nautilus
   notepadqq
   obsidian
   opam
   opera
   pageedit
   podman
   polypane
   privacybrowser
   qcam
   qmapshack
   qutebrowser
   rootlesskit
   rpm
   rssguard
   runc
   sbuild
   sbuild-abort
   sbuild-adduser
   sbuild-apt
   sbuild-checkpackages
   sbuild-clean
   sbuild-createchroot
   sbuild-destroychroot
   sbuild-distupgrade
   sbuild-hold
   sbuild-shell
   sbuild-unhold
   sbuild-update
   sbuild-upgrade
   scide
   signal-desktop
   slack
   slirp4netns
   steam
   stress-ng
   surfshark
   systemd-coredump
   thunderbird
   toybox
   trinity
   tup
   tuxedo-control-center
   userbindmount
   uwsgi-core
   vdens
   virtiofsd
   vivaldi-bin
   vpnns
   vscode
   wike
   wpcom
5 processes have profiles defined.
4 processes are in enforce mode.
   /usr/sbin/cups-browsed (2093) 
   /usr/sbin/cupsd (2005) 
   /usr/lib/cups/notifier/dbus (2080) /usr/sbin/cupsd
   /usr/sbin/rsyslogd (1769) rsyslogd
0 processes are in complain mode.
0 processes are in prompt mode.
0 processes are in kill mode.
1 processes are unconfined but have a profile defined.
   /usr/bin/nautilus (8546) nautilus
0 processes are in mixed mode.

Can anyone help me, please?
Thanks in advance.
Edit: Update 1 :
I did systemctl status apparmor and I got this:
● apparmor.service - Load AppArmor profiles
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/apparmor.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (exited) since Thu 2024-10-10 15:48:29 BST; 9min ago
       Docs: man:apparmor(7)
             https://gitlab.com/apparmor/apparmor/wikis/home/
   Main PID: 1388 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 901ms

oct 10 15:48:27 LaunchpadMcQuack systemd[1]: Starting apparmor.service - Load AppArmor profiles...
oct 10 15:48:27 LaunchpadMcQuack apparmor.systemd[1388]: Restarting AppArmor
oct 10 15:48:27 LaunchpadMcQuack apparmor.systemd[1388]: Reloading AppArmor profiles
oct 10 15:48:29 LaunchpadMcQuack apparmor.systemd[1552]: Warning: found usr.sbin.sssd in /etc/apparmor.d/force-complain, forcing complain mode
oct 10 15:48:29 LaunchpadMcQuack apparmor.systemd[1552]: Warning from /etc/apparmor.d (/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.sssd line 63): Caching disabled for: 'usr.sbin.sssd' due to force complain
oct 10 15:48:29 LaunchpadMcQuack systemd[1]: Finished apparmor.service - Load AppArmor profiles.

I am no expert by any means but I feel that those warnings are important here?

try sudo snap refresh ?

I just tried and it doesn't work. Still shows "snap-confine has elevated permissions...." etc

I just updated my original message.

I fixed it.
I used sudo snap disable snapd followed by sudo snap enable snapd, and this allowed all snaps to run normally.

lol, thanks it solved the problem. Why do I and you have the issue on the same day?

glad to be of help! that's actually crazy, it doesn't seem to be a common issue
